# Getting parsererror returned when trying to send mail using php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to send email from jquery using php, and I'm getting a parsererror:

#### index.html

```
var myUrl = "http://mysite/mail.php";
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: myUrl,
   cache: false,
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: {  body:"test",
            to:"myemail@gmail.com",
            subject:"Test Results"
         },
   dataType: "json",
   complete: function(transport, data){  
                console.log(data);
                if (transport.status == 200) 
                    alert("Worked.");
                else 
                    alert("Didn't work, " + transport.status); 
            }
   });
```

#### mail.php

```
<?php

$body = $_POST['body'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];

mail($to, $subject, $body);
?>
```

When I put `console.log(data)` in the index file, the result I see in the console is "parsererror." Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: There should never be a question that has both the php tag as well as the javascript tag (and by extension jquery, ext.js etc.). Investigate whether your client sends the wrong data or your server treats the data in a way that you did not intend it to.

Comment: @Oswald Well since I don't really know which side the problem is occuring on I didn't know which to pick. I would love to know which side is responsible, but I'm having trouble figuring that out. Help would be appreciated, I have basically 0 experience with php/json.

Comment: @pvnarula The "error" is that the mailing isn't working: however, this is the closest thing I have found to an actual problem, until now I had just seen that I wasn't getting the mail but I was unable to find anything that was going wrong within the program that might cause it.

Comment: you need to set up a SMTP server for sending mails

Answer (score 1):

The dataType you're specifying is JSON, meaning that the response that Javascript gets back from the request is expected to be JSON-encoded. Since you're not supplying any data at all from the PHP script, the Javascript is throwing an error.

Comment: So would I do that using an echo?

Comment: Yes, e.g.:
echo json_encode('the response you want to return');

Comment: I would want to return to, subject, and body to make sure they got through correctly: can I do that with one echo call or if I make 3 will they all still make it to the data object in index.html? EDIT - I suppose an array would work here.

Comment: You could do that with one echo call, creating a data structure inside json_encode that represents the data you want to return.